# Ladybug theme song identification

Tags: theme-song, miraculous-ladybug

[Ladybug PV](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FlwV3scCgAM). The anime is probably [Miraculous Ladybug](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Miraculous_Ladybug), but can anyone identify the title of the song used in this PV?

Comment: It is made by Toei and clearly is styled in the anime magical girl style though.

Comment: @MarchHo: That is a PV from 3 years ago. It's going to be a 3D film: http://www.pgsentertainment.com/property/11/miraculous-ladybug/

Comment: @nhahtdh You're right, but it appears to still have Toei in the credits, and the transformation scene is still Magical Girl.

Comment: The anime is, as you said, [Miraculous Ladybug](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Anime/MiraculousLadybug), but not much is known about it at the moment. The song **might** be titled *Ladybug* by Noam Kaniel, but again this is not confirmed. The lyrics and song can be found [here](http://playnewsongs.ru/pesni/noam-kaniel_miraculous-ladybug-promo-video-song).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You are right. The anime is indeed [Miraculous Ladybug](http://www.wikiwand.com/en/Miraculous_Ladybug). Now, there's a little issue with the title and the lyrics of the song.

According to the [Ladybug PV wiki site](http://miraculousladybug.wikia.com/wiki/Ladybug_PV),

> The song that plays with it is a test song titled [**Ladybug PV Song**](http://miraculousladybug.wikia.com/wiki/Ladybug_PV_Song) without true lyrics, having **English-like gibberish**, [lyrics can be found here](http://miraculousladybug.wikia.com/wiki/Ladybug_PV_Song).

Then they also state what Gao already said in the comment.

> The song in the video is titled **Ladybug** by **Noam Kaniel** and you can find the [lyrics to it here](http://playnewsongs.ru/pesni/noam-kaniel_miraculous-ladybug-promo-video-song).